# What is the purpose of using Youtube-style alphanumeric ids as URL slugs?

Tags: encryption, hash, url-redirection

I asked [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575022/generating-an-instagram-or-youtube-like-unguessable-string-id-in-ruby-activerec) on how to generate the alphanumeric/base64 resource IDs that Youtube, Instragram, and others use to identify videos/pictures/etc. Discussion led to the question of *why* these IDs are used.

I assumed it was for two reasons:

1. To shorten URLs from long integer IDs to shorter ones.
2. To prevent casual URL hacking by editing the URL in a browser.

Is this true? Why are these IDs used?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a security question.

Comment: I'm not sure where it should be asked, to be honest.

Comment: StackOverflow seems the logical place.

Comment: @Polynomial I'd give you -1 if I could. Kevboh has made an assumption about security and is asking whether he's right, and _why_ it would be used. If he's right, then someone should give an explanation behind the security. If not, they should help disavow him of the assumption. If you'd read the linked Stackoverflow question you'd see he'd asked *how* to implement this, which is exactly what that forum is for. This is about the security, hence it should be here.

Comment: @Iain My apologies, I missed the word "hacking" in reason #2. I guess it is a security question, then.

Comment: Instagram may be a better example. They use these slugs (e.g. http://instagram.com/p/P540i4ErdL/) and changing a character in them will result in a 404, which to me implies that it's for nominal security.

Comment: @Polynomial no probs. Kevboh, all that it implies is that not every combination has been used. If there is a resource that is public if you have the random number/string then it's not secure unless it's a big number/string, or you squeeze the time the resource is available. For example, Heroku put database backups on AWS, publicly, with a long random string in the url. This works because the resource is only available for 10 minutes, so the chance of an attacker guessing the url in that time is very small. A short url will not be private for long.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Youtube must produce URL by which the videos can be referenced. They prefer that the URL be short. They can choose the ID in any way that they see fit, provided that it matches their constraints, in particular:

- The ID must be unique (no two videos may share it).
- The ID must "work well" with whatever indexing mechanism they internally use.

Deriving the ID from the video "title" would be problematic in several ways: difficult to guarantee uniqueness, the usual Unicode-related mayhem when people have the insufferable arrogance of using characters which are not in the ASCII set, and string-based indexing (whereas I can imagine that a database would be happier with a 64-bit integer as indexing key).

There is *a priori* no security issue here. There *would be* a security issue if the URL were meant to reference non-public documents, in which case the ability to "guess" valid URL would be problematic (a possible solution would then be to include a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) in the ID). But Youtube videos are inherently public (they make no sense otherwise -- already, a number of them make no sense at all anyway).

Comment: Youtube has private (whitelist access) or unlisted (URL access) videos though.

Answer (score 2):

@kevboh, I don't think security is the primary concern, it's just a way for sites to keep resources straight in such a way that they are easy to differentiate. There's no security issue to fix; instagram and youtube want people to view their content, there's nothing they are trying to hide.

What security purpose would randomization serve in this case? Preventing people from guessing the date of creation of a resource when the date is already freely available to anyone that uses the content?

The main reason for randomization in this case is not to secure anything, but to ensure that people have to use the company's search tools and APIs to find the content. If you could guess contents' resource IDs you could bypass them, and because their business models are based on selling search choice information that could make them lose money.